# Belongs_to usage in ember js

Tags: ember.js

I want to show on page income name of each operation. I think i need to use belongs_to but i don't konw how.

I have two tables:

IncomeOperation: (id, sum, income_id)
Income: (id, name)

models/income.js.coffee

```
EmberMoney.Income = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
  description: DS.attr('string')
```

models/income_operation.js.coffee

```
EmberMoney.IncomeOperation = DS.Model.extend
  sum: DS.attr('number')
  incomeId: DS.belongsTo('EmberMoney.Income')  // I think i should be so
```

routes/addincome_route.js.coffee

```
EmberMoney.AddincomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    EmberMoney.IncomeOperation.createRecord()
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set('incomes', EmberMoney.Income.find())
    controller.set('operations', EmberMoney.IncomeOperation.find())
    controller.set('content', model)
```

templates/addincome.handlebars

```
    {{#each operation in controller.operations}}
      <div>
        // **Here i want to show income name instead of ID**
        {{operation.incomeId}}
        {{operation.storageId}}
        {{operation.sum}}
        {{operation.date}}
      </div>
    {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need to change `incomeId: DS.belongsTo('EmberMoney.Income')` to `income: DS.belongsTo('EmberMoney.Income')`.

after that, `{{operation.income.name}}` should give you the income name.